# How to find the next date with the same ID using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an recruitment audit table with columns like **Applicant_ID, Status**, **DateTime** (timestamp with the date and time the applicant got that status) and **Active_Status**(True/False).

The problem is I don't have a column with the timestamp the status got altered.

What I'm trying to do is this:

For every row where the **Active_Status** is False I'd like to find the rows with the same **Applicant_ID** and return the **DateTime** value which is the next in line (Bigger than the **DateTime** value of the actve row, but the smallest of the others) into a new column.

I'll have to do this again and again with tables with the same structure and are containing about 150k rows.

Example of the dataset:

```
Applicant_ID  Active_Status    Status    DateTime
 42830           True         Rejected   2018.08.06. 11:33:47 
 42830           False        Status1    2018.07.14. 6:46:04 
 42831           False        Status1    2018.07.14. 8:25:22 
 42831           True         Rejected   2018.08.06. 15:08:58 
 42832           False        Status1    2018.07.14. 9:03:37 
 42832           False        No         2018.07.16. 8:25:12 
 42832           True         Rejected   2018.08.31. 13:44:30
```

What would I like to create:

```
Applicant_ID  Active_Status    Status    DateTime                 Changed
 42830           True         Rejected   2018.08.06. 11:33:47     Active
 42830           False        Status1    2018.07.14. 6:46:04      2018.08.06. 11:33:47
 42831           False        Status1    2018.07.14. 8:25:22      2018.08.06. 15:08:58
 42831           True         Rejected   2018.08.06. 15:08:58     Active
 42832           False        Status1    2018.07.14. 9:03:37      2018.07.16. 8:25:12 
 42832           False        No         2018.07.16. 8:25:12      2018.08.31. 13:44:30 
 42832           True         Rejected   2018.08.31. 13:44:30     Active
```

Comment: Please add an example of your data and desired output.

Comment: A good read on preparing questions is here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Our dataset is not in english so I created something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on the [Pandas shift fucntion][1]

At first, you should normalize column with the date looking strings.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].apply(parse)
```

Sort values and apply shift function for each group

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Applicant_ID', 'DateTime'])
df['Changed'] = df.groupby('Applicant_ID').DateTime.shift(-1)
```

Result:

```
Applicant_ID    Active_Status   Status  DateTime            Changed
1      42830    False      Status1      2018-07-14 06:46:04 2018-08-06 11:33:47
0      42830    True       Rejected     2018-08-06 11:33:47 NaT
2      42831    False      Status1      2018-07-14 08:25:22 2018-08-06 15:08:58
3      42831    True       Rejected     2018-08-06 15:08:58 NaT
4      42832    False      Status1      2018-07-14 09:03:37 2018-07-16 08:25:12
5      42832    False      No           2018-07-16 08:25:12 2018-08-31 13:44:30
6      42832    True       Rejected     2018-08-31 13:44:30 NaT
```